# How to select multiple expressions in eventReactive shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I have two sidebarPanels - `Cond. 1` and `Cond. 2` and an action button `Compute`. I want to set two condition wherein,

- On selecting 'A' from Cond. 1 and 'B' from Cond. 2 and then 'Compute' gives some output
- On selecting 'C' from Cond. 1 and 'D' from Cond. 2 and then 'Compute' gives another output

What would be the right way to decribe this expression using eventReactive in the code below?

```
`eventReactive(c (input$Compute && input$Cond. 1=="A" && input$Cond. 2=="B",     
{  
stuff to execute
}`
```

Comment: Since any action depends on clicking the `compute` button, you only have to observe the button event, and then do an `if/else` check inside.

Comment: @warmoverflow : `eventReactive( input$Compute, {
if (input$Cond. 1=="A" && input$Cond. 2=="B") {
stuff to execute
}
}`
Think this would work?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Try it and see if it works.

Comment: @warmoverflow : Thank you! I'll check that out and let you know!